# Uncheck a checkbox with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to make a survey on a website with a question and three possible answers.

The problem is that i'm having trouble with the check/uncheck, I want to have only one answer checked, so if the user clicks on an answer and he has already checked an other one, it keeps only the last one.

Here is what I've done :

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var iSurveyId = $(this).closest('div').attr('name');
        var iAnswerId = $(this).closest('p').attr('value');
        var bIsChecked = 'true';
```

If the user click on a checkbox, I'll get the survey ID that is in the name of my div and the ID of my answer which is in my paragraph's name.

I'm using jQuery 1.1.12 so I can't use every function for exemple I can't use .prop().

Comment: use radio buttons rather than checkbox's

Comment: I'll do that this is true that it sounds way more logical but I'm still looking for an answer. This could help my understanding.

Comment: well your markup would define how you target the checkbox, but its simple enough to check/uncheck boxes: `$(".checkbox").attr("checked", false);`

Comment: If I may ask, why not use a newer version of jQuery?

Comment: I'm in an internship in a society, so I'm not the one who can ask for these kind of things, but probably that would mean to change a part of the past work (to "upgrade" the past code) to keep the code clean.

Comment: @JulienS I edited my answer. See it.

Comment: @JulienS If my answer is useful, please check it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input type radio instead of checkboxes so that all the user can only select one answer, or clear all the checkboxes first like this

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
     $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
     $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

The above should removed the checked attribute from all the select boxes and assign the checked attribute to the clicked one, or if you have multiple questions, each with multiple answers, you  can put the checkboxes in a div and change the code to:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    $('#div_id input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Comment: Your code is working but this doesn't keep the selected one (the last one is not checked).

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var thisChecked = $(this)[0].checked;
    $("input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
    
    if (thisChecked)
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    else 
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Item 1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Item 2</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Item 3</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Item 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: he can't use prop because of his jQuery version. change it to attr.

Comment: In the question, they said they can't use .prop()